# Java Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when loading Factual Instance

Tags: java

I am simple trying to Instantiate and instance of Factual class like so:

```
Factual factual = new Factual(key, secret);
```

Every time I start the load i get error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException`

I have loaded all the correct jar files and rechecked all the code to make sure I wasn't missing anything. All my imports are correct and dependencies are good.

Stack:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException
    at mygasfeedquery.FactualHelper.<init>(FactualHelper.java:19)
    at mygasfeedquery.mainGUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(mainGUI.java:320)
    at mygasfeedquery.mainGUI.access$200(mainGUI.java:18)
    at mygasfeedquery.mainGUI$3.actionPerformed(mainGUI.java:188)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

- guava-r09
- google-api-client-1.10.3-beta
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.1
- jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.1
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.1
- commons-io-2.1
- json-20090211
- junit-4.4
- factual-java-driver-1.5.0
- json-simple-1.1.1
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin

Comment: It is part of the Factual driver jar.

Comment: And you're sure that you're class-path is correct or that it is correctly attributed in your manifest file?

Comment: It looks like a dependence is not been met.  You need to make sure all the top levels Jars are included AND all the Jars they depend upon are included as well.

Comment: I have all the jars that the Factual driver is depending on. There are only 8 in the pom.xml file. Could on of the other jars conflict with it?

Comment: how are you executing the application?

Comment: I can execute the application put until I call the Factual driver. It all seems fine up to the point I do a button call and the line throws that exception.

I even created a new project and it still gave me the same exception. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @ Brandon Wilson its very sure that JVM Cannot load `Factual class` at run time it will compile. `Factual class` is not inyour class path. Ensure that you have downloaded the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was for dependency http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/1.7.0-beta

Once I loaded the google-api-client jar it gave me a new error. But then then someone mentioned that dependencies may depend of other dependencies. So I looked in the repo and found the ones that I needed based on that.

Basically I did not have all the jars that I needed for each one and I didn't know that dependencies can depend of each other.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occurs when any library jar file missing or unable to locate, if you're using netbeans framework and your project name in left side bar is displaying in red font color it indicates project need some fixing. To resolve this right-click on your project name then click on resolve project problem there it will tell you what the exactly problem there and which files are missing or unable to locate then you can set that missing files to your framework.